# FFMPEG on windows (for H.264 RTSP decoding)

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, h.264

Has anyone used the latest FFMPEG version for decoding H.264 based RTSP stream on windows environment using OpenCV.

My problem is that I am able to successfully decode H.264 based RTSP stream on Linux successfully but when I use the same code to decode H.264 based RTSP stream on windows the output is pretty much pixelated. Can someone tell me as to why there is a difference in behaviour (is it due to version mismatch)? Also how do I find out which version of FFMPEG is being used by the OpenCV SDK 2.1.0 and 2.2.0 available for windows?

Awaiting your response.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you compiled it with ffmpeg support?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know that you can decode RTPS stream using Opencv.
I have decode RTSP stream using Direct show techmology, I'd recommend using Directshow platform due  to low cpu consumption ,the video decoding is consumption  mostly consumed by the graphic card.

Instead of you , I'll chose to decode the RTSP stream using DirectShow platform, 
First install direct show SDK , then install FFD show ,

I'd recommend using filters taken from [elecard](http://www.elecard.com/en/index.html)
(I didn't find any other implementation for RTSP source filter).

Use edit graph to watch your [stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Great tuturial I have found is [this](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/DirectShow_For_Media_Playback_In_Windows-Part_I_Basics.shtml)  (Please read the continuation of this tuturial )

I'm not sure this would be the right answer for you , since I was using a totally different technology...